# How can you build 2 executables from 2 projects with one action in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

I have created a solution that looks like this:

- Solution

  - Shared Library DLL (project)
  - Utility Files (project)
  - Executable Project 1 (exe)
  - Executable Project 2 (exe)

Both executable projects reference the shared DLL and Utility classes, and they are independent of each other. Currently, the way I am compiling is to set Executable Project 1 as the "startup project", compile, then set Executable Project 2 as the "startup project" and compile again.

This process is tedious and will lead to missing executables if I were to leave the team and an uneducated person fills my role and doesn't realize how this is implemented.

Is there a way to produce both executables with one compilation step?

Comment: Use the "Build Solution" command (on the "Build" menu in the menu-bar, or right-click on the *Solution* (parent node) in the Solution Explorer and it's on that pop-up menu, too.

Comment: Oh dur. What an easy solution. Thanks! Now to make a post build step to copy/move the second exe to the first folder! :) Thanks!